# Is it possible to get the OS type of a remote host using Java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a Java code that can create a socket and initiate ssl handshake with a remote host. I need to know what type of OS the remote host is running. Is this possible with Java ? How? If not, any other solutions to make my Java program get this piece of information ?

I have checked similar question in: [How to check programmatically the OS of remote host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319368/how-to-check-programmatically-the-os-of-remote-host) Unfortunately, no answer was accepted. So, I post the question, possibly someone can provide an answer now.

Comment: It's not that simple, check out the tests nmap has to go through to determine/guess the remote OS.

Comment: An SSL handshake does not include any info about the OS.

Comment: @nos: Is there any other ways to get OS info ? not necessarily through the SSL handshake.

Comment: @Jury A Not unless you can run some code on the remote machine that pulls out that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [Host Fingerprinting](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/staff/bios/tfyen/publications/NDSS12-HostTracking.pdf), and is a very broad and deep topic with lots of research.  Your best bet is to invoke a tool such as [nmap](http://nmap.org/) in a subprocess and read its output.  Remember that even the best fingerprinting algorithm will be easily misled by NAT firewalls and proxies.

Comment: And if you want to use Nmap you should check out Nmap4j on sourceforge.net, it's a simple wrapper API that invokes nmap and converts the results into Java objects for you. It's compatible with the latest Nmap as well.